# How can I deploy My twtter project on Vercel

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js, vercel

I have created this twitter clone project using (node, express, html, mysql(using sequelize), and JS) I want to deploy it to vercel but am having trouble doing so.  When I do import via github and try to deploy my site the outcome is a error 500 it is not able to use the server.  Here is a link to my code: https://github.com/ZohaibA99/TwitterProject

I already tried using the vercel.json file implementation however it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi, what are these errors? Check logs on Vercel and include them editing your question